# SearchField sapui5 show data from json

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I already bind json data to view in sapui5. but I want show value in toast from json by selected id.

**JSON data:**

```
var data_suggest = [{"key":"1","value":"value dari 1", "description": "Satu"},
                    {"key":"2","value":"value dari 2", "description": "Dua"},
                    {"key":"3","value":"value dari 3", "description": "Tiga"}]
```

**view:**

```
                <m:SearchField id="idSearchBy" 
                               enableSuggestions="true"
                               suggest="onSuggest" 
                               liveChange="onLiveChange"
                               search="onSearchBy"
                               placeholder="Search..."
                               suggestionItems="{
                                    path: 'suggest_model>/',
                                    sorter: {path : 'suggest_model>value'}
                               }">                  
                    <m:suggestionItems>
                        <m:SuggestionItem text="{suggest_model>value}" key="{suggest_model>key}"/>
                    </m:suggestionItems>    
                </m:SearchField>
```

I want when run onSearchBy function, showing value key, value, and description from JSON by selected id form SearchField.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works:

```
<SearchField
    id="idSearchBy"
    placeholder="Search for..."
    enableSuggestions="true"
    search="onSearch"
    suggest="onSuggest"
    suggestionItems="{
        path: '/suggest_model',
        sorter: { path: 'key' }
    }"
>
    <suggestionItems>
        <SuggestionItem text="{value}" key="{key}"/>
    </suggestionItems>
</SearchField>
```

You can check and download the [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.SearchFieldSuggestions/code).